# Position text vertically center in div with CSS

Tags: html, css

I'd like to position all my text vertically centered within the div.

Currently 'Chat to us online now' is at the top of the div.

How do I achieve this using my code?

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/jL5bpmp1/

```css
* {
    margin:0
}

.box {
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    background-color:#0f89cf;
    height:55px;
    width:100%;
    padding:5px 0 0 0;
    margin-bottom:30px
}

.box img, .box div {
    float:left;
    margin-left:10px
}

.box h1 {
    color:#fff;
    font-size:18px   
}

.box h1 span {
    display:block;
    font-size:23px
}
```

```html
<div class="is-mobile">

<div class="box">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
    <div>
        <h1>Chat to us online now</h1> 
    </div>
</div>

<div class="box">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
    <div>
        <h1>Call the Helpline
        <span>101 2333 9302</span></h1>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="box">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
    <div>
        <h1>Make a General Enquiry
        <span>101 2333 9303</span></h1>
    </div>
</div>
    
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to use `display:inline-block` instead of `float:left`, then you can set up the vertical align value easily.

```
.box img, .box div {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

**[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jL5bpmp1/10/)**

Comment: I like this method a lot. Feels very old browser compliant too :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this common vertical centering method:

```
.box div {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```css
* {
    margin:0
}

.box {
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    background-color:#0f89cf;
    height:55px;
    width:100%;
    padding:5px 0 0 0;
    margin-bottom:30px
}

.box img, .box div {
    float:left;
    margin-left:10px
}

.box h1 {
    color:#fff;
    font-size:18px   
}

.box h1 span {
    display:block;
    font-size:23px
}

.box div {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="is-mobile">

<div class="box">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
    <div>
        <h1>Chat to us online now</h1> 
    </div>
</div>

<div class="box">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
    <div>
        <h1>Call the Helpline
        <span>101 2333 9302</span></h1>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="box">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
    <div>
        <h1>Make a General Enquiry
        <span>101 2333 9303</span></h1>
    </div>
</div>
    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your browser support is IE10+ you can use flex-box. You just need to add 2 lines:

```
.box {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0;
}
```

I also added `padding: 0;` as you don't need that now you're using flex-box. Welcome to the future. The best place to learn about flexbox is here:

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/